Debugging dump file
I have created an small application in WPF and powershell and packaged to an exe to allow it to be used by other users. I have done this many times and they always seem to work fine. However this one is causing issues.
It works fine may i add when i right click and run with powershell. Issue comes when running the created exe. I creted this using WIN-PS2EXE.
It loads the password prompts then the modules then is appears to never display. Yet it runs in the background and i have to kill the task to close it. It does the same on other machines as well.
Ran the created dumpfile through Windbg.
I have ran the debug application and i am getting the below but not finding much as to what it could be
Symbol search path is: srv*
Executable search path is: srv*
ModLoad: 00000000`00b30000 00000000`00bd0000   image00000000`00b30000
ModLoad: 00007ffb`72dd0000 00007ffb`72fc8000   ntdll.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffb`56510000 00007ffb`56575000   C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MSCOREE.DLL
ModLoad: 00007ffb`71bd0000 00007ffb`71c8d000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNEL32.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffb`70480000 00007ffb`70776000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffb`6a270000 00007ffb`6a300000   C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\apphelp.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffb`6f030000 00007ffb`6f042000   C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\kernel.appcore.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffb`54850000 00007ffb`551f4000   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffb`5afd0000 00007ffb`5afdc000   C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\VCRUNTIME140_1_CLR0400.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffb`55a40000 00007ffb`55a5b000   C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\VCRUNTIME140_CLR0400.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffb`55970000 00007ffb`55a3d000   C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ucrtbase_clr0400.dll
(21b0.22c8): Unknown exception - code 04242420 (first chance)
ModLoad: 00007ffb`70e00000 00007ffb`70e08000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\psapi.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffb`52400000 00007ffb`53a0f000   C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\mscorlib\987f639e2113a820112aca65fb12396c\mscorlib.ni.dll
(8240.1e0c): Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)
ntdll!LdrpDoDebuggerBreak+0x30:
00007ffb`72ea0730 cc              int     3

The dump file is giving me the below when i run !analyze -v
TACK_COMMAND:  ~0s; .ecxr ; kb

SYMBOL_NAME:  win32u!NtUserMsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx+14

MODULE_NAME: win32u

IMAGE_NAME:  win32u.dll

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  BREAKPOINT_80000003_win32u.dll!NtUserMsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx

OS_VERSION:  10.0.19041.1

BUILDLAB_STR:  vb_release

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64

OSNAME:  Windows 10

IMAGE_VERSION:  10.0.19041.4123

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {ab2d2e3e-edb3-a979-68f2-e3be023a5515}

Followup:     MachineOwner

There are no breakpoints in the PS code or the XAML code.
!analyze -v -hang shows:
STACK_COMMAND:  ~0s ; .cxr ; kb

SYMBOL_NAME:  win32u!NtUserMsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx+14

MODULE_NAME: win32u

IMAGE_NAME:  win32u.dll

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  APPLICATION_HANG_cfffffff_win32u.dll!NtUserMsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx

OS_VERSION:  10.0.19041.1

BUILDLAB_STR:  vb_release

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64

OSNAME:  Windows 10

IMAGE_VERSION:  10.0.19041.4123

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {d44568b7-4ea6-d9b8-71f9-5e0773589878}

Followup:     MachineOwner
---------

I have run SFC and DISM as a few suggested online but still get the same.

My Winform program also encountered the same problem, this problem appeared once on both computers.I found through the event viewer that Windows was updating when these two problems occurred, and I found win32u.dll has been modified.
I have run my program multiple times since then and this problem has not occurred again.
I'm not sure if it's caused by the update, but it's currently normal.
